# The Markdown Editing Help page cannot be read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, editing

The [Markdown Editing Page](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) cannot be read...unless having all the helping code/examples being hidden behind a spoiler is on purpose as to not spoil the amazing secrets that proper markdown editing provides.

I seriously couldn't get any help from this page at all...

I'm using Chrome ver 16.0.912.75 as my browser if that makes any difference

[image]

Comment: It's a background/text color thing. I checked and if I highlighted a section I could read where it was selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oops, yeah, I see why you didn't find that helpful :)

Fixed in the next build of the site; thanks!

Comment: Not to sound impatient, but when is the next rebuild coming?

Comment: @Yawus It probably happened that same day, about 14 months ago. Are you trying to tell me something?

Comment: Ah, because I'm still running into this problem. Sorry, I noted the month but not the year. Or at least I did when I was on my desktop at home... Odd. I'll try to reproduce.

Comment: Can you give me a screenshot of what you mean?